# A common set of problems to learn new languages

Tags: programming-languages

With "Polyglot" programming techniques becoming more relevant, it is almost a necessity to use the "right" PL for the problem. However, learning new languages takes time which usually most project team can't afford. What is the best way to learn a new programming language? Is there a common set of problems  that can be solved to reach a certain level of competence?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what you want to do. (web, db, whatever).

Generally I'd want to know:

- What's the library like, how do I reference it
- What ORMs are there
- What build/deployment platforms exist for it
- How does it handle updates
- How do I do general things, like:

  - DB Access
  - File things
  - Display UI's

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Really, learning is only by doing -- you need a project that you can use the given language for.

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is the first thing to come to mind as an oft-used set of problems to try in a new language, even if it's not something I've ever tried.

If the language is another JVM or CLR hosted one, the issues about learning the environment can be set aside -- you can use all your familiar APIs in your Clojure/Scala/F#... code -- and concentrate on the syntax and idiom.

Otherwise, you're probably using the new language because it has a good fit for the particular problem you want to solve (e.g. native code and functional -> Haskell; distributed and concurrent -> Erlang) so the fit of the feature set is known in advance but you have the extra load of learning the standard APIs.  And that's what prototyping is for.

Answer (score 0):

The book [Programming Challenges](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387001638) and the [associated website](http://www.programming-challenges.com/pg.php?page=index) provide a large list of algorithmic problems, with automatic online judging in several languages (Java, C, C++). Any algorithm textbook can give you lots of examples of basic data structures and procedures to try and implement, which is often a nice way to get some practice with basic language syntax and features. My personal favourite for this is [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/), which is language agnostic, but there are plenty of good language-specific books available as well ([Mastering Algorithms in Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565923980/) or [Data Structures and Algorithms in Java](http://ww0.java4.datastructures.net/), for example).

If you're interested in a general set of mathematical problems to try and solve, [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is a great resource.

For more day to day problems, I find the cookbook approach most helpful. For example, both Perl and Python have excellent O'Reilly cookbooks, as well as [online resources](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/), which provide short examples of many common and important problems. As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310018/a-common-set-of-problems-to-learn-new-languages/1310025#1310025), the key here is to find canonical examples of basic features you will need, particularly by leveraging what's available in standard libraries. I usually try and build up my own small library of examples as I go along, e.g. a socket example, a DB access example, a file reading example, a simple numerical solver, etc, which I then pillage for ideas when it's time to write production code.